# R: multivariate formula notation. Dependent variable

Tags: r, regression

What's the difference between:... ?

`lm( cbind(y1,y2) ~ x)`

and

`lm( y1 + y2 ~ x)`

Where y1 and y2 are dependent variables, and I want to do a regression analysis of both at the same time, to get more power.
What method assumes the same variance?

Comment: Perhaps you should run examples of both models: the distinction will immediately be apparent.

Answer (score 4):

If you are ever in doubt, look at the model frames or model matrices that R computes from the symbolic formula.

In the case of `y1 + y2 ~ x`, R forms the summation of `y1` and `y2` element-wise

```
> dat <- data.frame(y1 = rnorm(10), y2 = rnorm(10), x = runif(10))
> model.frame(y1 + y2 ~ x, data = dat)
        y1 + y2          x
1   0.006279284 0.64626672
2   0.396766920 0.07468028
3   1.627806415 0.82183379
4   0.187610350 0.30198154
5  -0.265074134 0.57927559
6   2.227391043 0.05672303
7   1.768102382 0.12088628
8  -0.096506485 0.92434075
9   1.531045263 0.21717877
10 -1.472182623 0.06527650
```

something we can easily confirm

```
> with(dat, y1 + y2)
 [1]  0.006279284  0.396766920  1.627806415  0.187610350 -0.265074134
 [6]  2.227391043  1.768102382 -0.096506485  1.531045263 -1.472182623
```

Hence this model specification is univariate where the response is $y_i = y1_i + y2_i$

In the case of `cbind(y1, y2) ~ x`, R forms a multivariate linear model with two responses

```
> model.frame(cbind(y1, y2) ~ x, data = dat)
   cbind(y1, y2).y1 cbind(y1, y2).y2          x
1         0.1870238       -0.1807445 0.64626672
2        -0.3277228        0.7244898 0.07468028
3         0.4549313        1.1728751 0.82183379
4         1.1795594       -0.9919491 0.30198154
5        -0.7562194        0.4911453 0.57927559
6         1.5077446        0.7196465 0.05672303
7         1.0760983        0.6920041 0.12088628
8        -1.2932155        1.1967090 0.92434075
9         0.8108233        0.7202220 0.21717877
10       -0.3714595       -1.1007231 0.06527650
```

You'll also notice that when you fit the model, the resulting object inherits from class `mlm` to indicate that it is a multivariate linear model

```
> mod <- lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ x, data = dat)
> class(mod)
[1] "mlm" "lm"
```

Comment: Thanks.  I don't know why they didn't use the same formula notation on the left side.

Comment: Do you know if it's the same for lme4 and nlme?

Comment: What assumptions does R when you use "cbind(y1, y2) ~ x" ?  Variances,...

Comment: Unfortunatelly I've tried with glm(cbind(y1,y2)~x, family = "binomial") and it seems it doesn't work in the same way, it says "logical subscript too long"

Comment: Where in `?glm` does it say you can do this with respect to a *multivariate* GLM? You can use a matrix as one way to set up a *univariate* binomial GLM, but you can't fit a multivariate GLM using `glm()`.

Comment: Interesting, is it actually possible to do a multivariate GLM in R?

Comment: @M.Beausoleil No, not via `glm()`.

Comment: Do you know how in R? A quick function. I’ve tried to search for one but I found only stuff about correlational Glm or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean by a multivariate GLM?

Comment: @GavinSimpson I mean a Glm where you have multiple y variable. It seems that you say that using cbind(y)~x1+x2 is not a multivariate Glm.